# MVC3 Scaffolding - customize view templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I'm using the MVCScaffolding nuget package.

Where can I find documentation on the values we can use when customizing our MVC scaffolding templates?

i.e. I have done

```
PM> scaffold CustomTemplate View Edit
```

which creates the Edit.cs.t4 template for me. It has things like:

```
<#= Model.ViewDataTypeName  ?? String.Empty #>
```

I would like to use something like

```
<#= Model.ViewDataPluralisedName  ?? String.Empty #>
```

but because there is no Intellisense, I have no idea what fields are available to me.

Does someone know where the documentation for this is?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx?PageIndex=2 might help you getting started.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'd already seen that link, but it doesn't document what properties there are on the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation, but I was able to find out what I needed to know by downloading the mvc scaffolding source code from http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/ and looking in there.